# key duplicates in the array in mongodb even using $addToSet

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like this 
schema

```
{
    'cr':[
              { key: 'key1', value:['value1','value2','value3'] },
              { key: 'key2', value:['value4','value5','value6'] }
         ]
}

function addCriteriaKey(id,key,callback){
    var options = { new: false ,select:'_id'};
        Model.update({'uid':id},{'$addToSet':{'cr':{'key':key}}},options,function(err,data){
           if(err) callback(err,null);
           else callback(null,data);
        })  
}

function addCriterialValueToKey(id,key,value,callback){
    var options = { new: false ,select:'_id'};
        Model.update({'uid':id,'cr.key':key},{'$addToSet':{'cr.$.val':value}},options,function(err,data){
            if(err) callback(err,null);
            else callback(null,data);
        })  
}
```

so here is my two methods to add a key and add a value, they all works, however the database has one existing key, but I added a extra key, $addToSet doesn't to work anymore.

For example
when I have done this:

**1.** addCriteriaKey('id','abc',function(err,data){})

**2.** addCriterialValueToKey('id','abc','111',function(err,data){})

the data becomes like

```
{
    'cr':[
              { key: 'abc', value:['111'] }              
         ]
}
```

but when I added key 'abc' again.
1. addCriteriaKey('id','abc',function(err,data){})

the data becomes like

```
{
    'cr':[
              { key: 'abc', value:['111'] },
              { key: 'abc' }                
         ]
}
```

it seems the $addToSet doesn't work anymore , What I should do to prevent this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$addToSet checks whole object not a perticular value only so in your case

```
{ key: 'abc', value:['111'] } 
and
{ key: 'abc'}
```

both are different for $addToSet

if you want to ensure unique key then you should create a unique index for that like this.

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { 'cr.key': 1 }, { unique: true } );
```

Comment: Thanks, Shreyance, this helps a lot

Comment: @user824624 You can accept the answer if it solved your purpose. thanks:)